# How can I check whether a JRuby script defines a particular method?

Tags: ruby, jruby

I'm embedding Ruby within a Java app via JRuby, and need to test whether a given Ruby script defines various methods. I have a very simple JRuby setup:

```
ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer();
Object receiver = container.runScriptlet(new FileReader(SCRIPT_PATH));
```

where `SCRIPT_PATH` is a File with these contents:

```
def processDoc(doc)
  return doc
end
```

I now want to determine whether the script defined the `processDoc` method, but can't find a way other than actually invoking `processDoc`, which I'd prefer to avoid. I've tried `respond_to? 'processDoc'` and `methods.include? 'processDoc'`, neither of which works, as the following successful set of assertions indicates:

```
Object doc = new Object();
assert container.runScriptlet("respond_to? :processDoc") == Boolean.FALSE;
assert container.runScriptlet("methods().include? 'processDoc'") == Boolean.FALSE;
assert receiver == null;
assert container.callMethod(receiver, "processDoc", doc) == doc;
```

Are there any other techniques I can use to determine if a simple JRuby script defines a method with a particular name, without actually invoking the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining a global method, it becomes a private method of `Object`.  You must therefore use the `include_all` parameter for [`respond_to?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) to get this to work:

```
container.runScriptlet("Object::respond_to?(:processDoc, true)")
```